# Recurrence relation for $n$ digit numbers not containing '$20$'

Tags: recurrence-relations

How many n digits base $3$ numbers do exist such that they never contain pattern '$20$'?
(first find a recurrence relation)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you list out the number of cases for small values of $n$? Can you guess what the recurrence is?

Comment: trying to guess is used for find closed form of sequence, but in this case i want a recurrence relation.

Comment: Yes, but that offers you a way to figure out what the recurrence relation is, which makes proving it easier (if you have no idea how to approach it).

Comment: Can you have numbers with leading zeroes?  Like $0000112_3$?

Comment: @John That doesn't really matter, since you can subtract those cases away after you have done the calculation.

Comment: @John Yes we can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $a(n)$ be the sequence we are looking for. Let $b(n) , c(n), d(n)$ be the number of ternary strings (and so they can start with 0) which do not contain the pattern '20', and start with 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

What equations can you get?

Claim: $a(n) = b(n) + c(n) + d(n)$.
Claim: $b(n) = c(n) = b(n-1) + c(n-1) + d(n-1)$.
Claim: $d(n) = c(n-1) + d(n-1)$.

Can you take it from here?

$b(n) = a(n-1)$, $d(n) = a(n-1) - b(n-1) = a(n-1) - a(n-2)$. Hence ...

Comment: I need recurrence relation in a form like this:
A(n)=bA(n-1)+c

Comment: @Emad Yes, and it's a short skip to the end, which you can finish out. Note that the recurrence relation could involve more terms than just 2, which is why I asked you to guess what it looks like first. It will be of the form $a(n) = Ba(n-1) + Ca(n-2) + D$, where $B, C, D$ are constants.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dear @Calvin:)